# apt-get update 404 Debian 5.0.4

Tags: debian, apt, debian-lenny

Hi I have a NAS(My book live) with Debian 5.0.4 and when I run

```
apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org wheezy Release
```

Here is my sources list

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

Output of

```
lsb_release -da

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.4 (lenny)
Release:    5.0.4
Codename:   lenny
```

Any suggestions how to fix it? I am trying to get latest package of duplicity.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze#Links

Comment: @IporSircer can you explain a little more with exact steps? I am very new to Linux.

Comment: Squeezy is quite old, it is only available on archive server. The best you can do just simply ignore the error.

Comment: @IporSircer I was to install latest of duplicity http://duplicity.nongnu.org/  Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an EOL debian release. First you need to edit you `sources.list` by commenting out all urls :

```
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
#deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
#deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

Then add the following lines:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ lenny contrib main non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main
```

Install the `debian-archive-keyring` package :

```
sudo apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
sudo apt-get update
```

**NB** An EOL debian release doesn't receive the security updates.

Comment: thanks for the instructions. they mainly seem to work but I do get this warning

Comment: Errors went away.. magically.  Thanks for the help.