# Debian apt-get update 404 not found error

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, apt

My Raspberry Pi 3 is having problems. When I try to run `apt-get update`, I get a 404 not found error. I am very new to Linux and I am not sure what is wrong.

Here is the error code:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease                            
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg                             
--*cut*--

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks like this:

```bsh
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` file looks like this:

```bsh
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
```

Please help. I can provide more information if necessary.

Note: Chromium, ping (from bash shell) is working.

Note: The sites that were not able to be fetched are not reachable from another computer using the same WiFi, (nor on the Raspberry Pi 3) e.g. http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages gives a 404 Not Found Error.

https://superuser.com/a/1133746/1498871 has something about a EOL Debian version. Is this my problem?

I have tried a few of the Super User posts on this topic, but none of the solutions that I have tried have worked.

Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie) is the descriptor line from `lsb_release -a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version of Debian was obsoleted in 2017 or thereabouts. The Raspberry Pi Foundation doesn't support it anymore.

The simplest way is to start with the latest Raspberry Pi OS, reapply whatever changes you've made (I have a fairly [simple set of instructions on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/540885/how-do-i-duplicate-a-server/540888#540888) on how I'd do it) and work from there.

Alternatively you could *try* upgrading the distro, but on single board computers, there's occasionally strangeness that you won't find on x86es, and it depends on the repos still being available.

If you have *anything* important on the SD card/install *please* back it up.

Then things get interesting. The 'previous' version of Raspbian is "Stretch". The current one is "Buster", the next one "Bullseye" is about to be released soon - you have Jessie.

In theory, if the repos are still up, you can modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `*.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and replace `jessie` with `stretch`, do an `apt update` then an `apt full-upgrade`, then do it again, replacing `stretch` with `buster` (and soon in another step `buster` with `bullseye`) - doing it for one version is [mentioned in the docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/os.html#updating-and-upgrading-raspberry-pi-os) but jumping multiple versions isn't something I've seen people do - do it in steps. On the bright side, if things fail you have a backup and can work from there.

Comment: Just a heads up: bullseye is now released.

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this same issue but didn't want to go through the work of upgrading versions, so simply updated the mirror link in my `sources.list` from `mirrordirector.raspbian.org` to `legacy.raspbian.org`

**sources.list**

```bash
deb http://legacy.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Method from [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=294581) where someone ran into the same issue using Wheezy - an even older [Raspbian version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS#Releases).

Comment: I guess that's reasonable - but there's a point where keeping older versions around is counterproductive. That said, I have a bit of a bias from helping maintain an appliance with 8.04 as a base...

Comment: Seems to work... isn't the best solution though... In the future  you will likely run into software compatability problems. Thank you for answering!

Comment: 100% Thanks - wish that was clearer to understand vs. a rug pull.